# Where are the Shards of Mehrune's Razor?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I visited and cleared the Cracked Tusk Keep prior to getting the "Pieces of the Past" quest. Now that I've returned to the Cracked Tusk Vault to complete the quest, I cannot find the "Shards of Mehrune's Razor". They are not on the alter nor are they in my inventory? Where could they be?

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be a known bug.

http://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Pieces_of_the_Past

> Should you discover and clear one of the locations, and kill the
>   "boss" prior to receiving a Museum Pamphlet, the quest will become
>   impossible to complete.

However, you may be able to respawn the whole area.  Go away from Cracked Tusk, rest for 30 days, and come back.  This should respawn the boss.

Comment: okay cool!... I'll let ya know if this works. Cheers!

Comment: This weapon is mainly for being a collector's item.  It's relatively mundane, especially if you have Dragonborn and can eventually craft Dragonbone weapons.